# Laravel lmage conversion to WebP using cwebp failed with error code 126

Tags: linux, laravel, webp

I am using Laravel 7.30.0 and this [buglinjo/laravel-webp](https://github.com/buglinjo/laravel-webp) package to generate the WebP images from the uploaded files. I have downloaded the cwebp program from google itself. When I developing locally using Windows, the package works fine, and the webp images created successfully. But when I upload my project to the staging, which is using Linux, The webp script returns this error:

`staging.ERROR: Image conversion to WebP using cwebp failed with error code 126.`
and  `No output was sent to stdout`.

I have downloaded the cwebp driver for both Linux 32 bit and 64 bit, and changed the package config inside the `config/laravel-webp.php` file. But I still get the same error.

Can anyone please help me with this problem? Thanks in advance.